# Does returning a response in Flask without waiting for threads to complete cause any unexpected behavior in production?

Tags: flask, gunicorn, python-multithreading

I have an endpoint in my Flask application where I want to perform some tasks asynchronously and not wait for them to complete before returning a response. I want to make sure that the return statement does not close the threads and leave them incomplete. I've implemented the following code, and it seems to be working fine in my tests:

```py
def fake_endpoint():
    # Create a ThreadPoolExecutor
    executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor()
    # Submit api_request to the executor
    executor.submit(api_request)
    # Submit another task to the executor
    executor.submit(task)
    # Shutdown the executor when tasks will finish, but don't wait for them to finish
    executor.shutdown(wait=False)
    # Return and exit the function
    return "OK", 200
```

However, I'm concerned about potential unexpected behavior in a production environment. Are there any known issues or concerns with this approach when using Flask or Gunicorn? Could this code cause any problems or lead to resource leaks if used in a high-traffic production application? Are there any best practices or alternative approaches that I should consider?